# Unexpected type(s): (int, int) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex, None) (slice, Iterable[None])

Tags: python, pycharm

What's wrong with this code:

```py
split_list = [3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 45]
split_list2 = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
result = [3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 45, None, None, None]

for i in range(len(split_list)):
    split_list2[i] = split_list[i]
```

In PyCharm it issues a warning;

> ***Unexpected type(s): (int, int) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex, None) (slice, Iterable[None])***

But the script runs just fine and this code works exactly as I expected. I don't like warnings in my IDE though, any quick fixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning is solved by updating to PyCharm to 2021.2.2.

It seems to be a bug in earlier versions of the IDE's static type checker.

One user reported in the comments that this bug regressed in the PyCharm 2021.2.3 release.

I just tested it again using PyCharm 2022.1 Professional Edition and the bug has again been solved. Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of code in IDE's editor window]

Comment: Still happens in 2021.2.3. Is there another fix?

Comment: @Gulzar I just checked it on PyCharm 2022.1 and it's working again, the bug likely had a brief regression during your version. Solution is to update the IDE, no other workarounds except disabling the warning but a better solution is to ignore the warning until you update.

Comment: Bug is back as of 2023.2.1 (Community Edition)

Comment: Bug still present in 2023.3.2 (Community Edition)